# Merge array values with diffrent property names

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I’ve two arrays of objects with `name` `value` and `id`

Array A

```
ArrayA:  [{
    name: ,
    value: ,
    key: 
},
];
```

I’ve another array of objects but with diffretns names of properties

```
ArrayB:  [{
    user: “userA” ,
    email: “emailA”,
    key:1: 
},
{
    user: “userB” ,
    email: “emailB”,
    key: 
},
];
```

Now I want to That`ArrayA` will have the values from ArrayB. I mean user => name and email => value

ArrayA should have the following entries

```
  ArrayA:  [{
        name: “userA” ,
        value: “emailA”,
        key: 1
    },
        name: “userB” ,
        value: “emailB”,
        key: 1
    ]
```

I’ve tried to use `map` but without success, any idea what am I missing here?

```
ArrayA = ArrayB.map(((item: { name: string; value: string }) => (item.user, item.email))
```

I Can use a loop, there is better way to to it ?

Should I use lodash?

Comment: Instead of an array you can maintain an `object`, if you need to rename the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ArrayA` is useless here, 
You can just use `map()` over `ArrayB` and return the Array with the properties you need.

```js
const ArrayB = [
  {
    user: "dani" ,
    email: "dani@gmail.com",
    key:1 
  },
  {
    user: "john" ,
    email: "john@gmail.com",
    key:2
  }
]

const res = ArrayB.map(({ user, email, key }) => ({
  name: user,
  value: email,
  key 
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, Im using typescript, do you know what should I put here ? `(({ user, email, key })` the property sould be strings...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Array concat() Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
let ArrayA = [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        value: '22',
        key: 5,
    },
];

let ArrayB = [
    {
        name: 'name2',
        value: '33',
        key: 6,
    },
];

let ArrayC = ArrayA.concat(ArrayB);

let ArrayD = ArrayA.concat([{ name: 'name2' }, { value: '33' }, { key: 6 }]);


console.log(ArrayC);
console.log(ArrayA);
console.log(ArrayD); //ref sreenshot
```

[image: Array]

You can't have elements in the array directly like what you have specified, they need to an object to have a key value relationship

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the key by maintaining an `object`. Something like this:

```js
var obj={ user:'name', email:'value', key:'key' };
var arrayA=[{name:'somevalue', value:'somevalue', key:''}];
var arrayB= [{ user: 'userA' , email: 'emailA', key:'1' }, { user: 'userB' , email: 'emailB', key:'' }];

arrayA = [...arrayA, ...arrayB.map(k=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(k).map(([key,v])=>[obj[key],v])))];

console.log(arrayA)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use spread operator and map:

```
const result = [...ArrayA, ...ArrayB.map(({ key, user, email }) => ({ key, name: user, value: email }))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of these objects having a means of translation might be nice.

Plain old JavaScript with Object.fromEntries has a solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

```
objA = {
    name: 'user',
    value: 'email',
    key: 1
};

objB = {
    user: 'user',
    email: 'email',
    key: 1
};

function translate(object) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(objB)
            .map(([key, value]) => {
                let newKey;
                switch(key) {
                    case 'user':
                        newKey = 'name';
                        break;
                    case 'value':
                        newKey = 'email';
                        break;
                    default:
                        newKey = key;
                }
                return [newKey, value];
            })
    );
}

const originalObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objB));
const newObject = translate(originalObject);

console.log(originalObject);
console.log(newObject);
```

With an output of:

```
{ user: 'user', email: 'email', key: 1 }
{ name: 'user', email: 'email', key: 1 }
```

You can map the arrays with the function just as you have in your solution.